# How to create reg_binary from string value?

Tags: vbscript

This is something that I have to once and will never have to do it again. I want to create REG_BINARY from a string. There's a program that encodes the password and stores it in the registry as REG_BINARY. I have copied the REG_BINARY and stored it in my database as varchar (i.e. string). So, whenever user logs in to any computer in the network, this REG_BINARY needs to be applied to the Registry value.

Here's what I tried.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Create the ADsystem Information Object
Set objADSystemInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
'Get the current information into a new object
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objADSystemInfo.UserName)

'Office Details
oShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Common\UserInfo\UserInitials", objUser.sAMAccountName, "REG_SZ"
oShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Common\UserInfo\UserName", objUser.givenName & " " & objUser.sn, "REG_SZ"

On Error Resume Next

'Connect to MySQL Database
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adUseClient = 3

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConnection.Open "DSN=members;"
objRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient
objRecordset.ActiveConnection = objConnection


objRecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM members WHERE USER_ID = '" & objUser.sAMAccountName & "'"


aRegPath = "HKCU\Software\KONICA MINOLTA\KONICA MINOLTA 350/250/200 VXL\AccountTrack\"
oShell.RegWrite aRegPath & "DepartmentName", objRecordset("USER_ID"), "REG_SZ"
oShell.RegWrite aRegPath & "DepartmentPass", objRecordset("DEPARTMENT_PASS"), "REG_BINARY"
```

The `USER_ID` shows up in the registry, but not the `DEPARTMENT_PASS`. I think it's cause the department_pass is stored as string. The value of the department_pass from the database is:

`be 2e 31 df ff 53 ca 35 f8 32 90 22 fc 44 4b 66 f8 32 90 22 fc 44 4b 66 f8 32 90 22 fc 44 4b 66 f8 32 90 22 fc 44 4b 66 f8 32 90 22 fc 44 4b 66 f8 32 90 22 fc 44 4b 66 f8 32 90 22 fc 44 4b 66 32 88 64 99 7b ab 8d 3c`

The registry needs to show this value exactly the way it is. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have to write VB scripts a lot, I didn't really care to learn it much. I do understand what @Ansgar Wiechers was trying to do, but it didn't work out for me. However, I found this link https://rcmtech.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/vbscript-and-reg_binary-registry-values/ that pointed me to the write direction. I just had to adjust a couple things for my need and get the value from the database, then it worked.

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfdfhz1b%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

> **RegWrite** will write at most one DWORD to a REG_BINARY value. Larger values are not supported with this method.

What you're trying to do requires the [`SetBinaryValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa393286%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI method:

```
Const HKCU = &h80000001

Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")

key   = "Software\KONICA MINOLTA\KONICA MINOLTA 350/250/200 VXL\AccountTrack"
name  = "DepartmentPass"
value = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

rc = reg.SetBinaryValue(HKCU, key, name, value)
If rc <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "Error setting binary value"
  WScript.Quit 1
End If
```

Since `SetBinaryValue` expects `value` to be an array of integers you need to convert the value of `objRecordset("DEPARTMENT_PASS")` (probably a string) to that first:

```
str = objRecordset("DEPARTMENT_PASS")
ReDim value(Len(str) - 1)
For i = 1 To Len(str)
  c = Mid(str, i, 1)
  value(i-1) = Asc(c)
Next
```

Comment: I had to change the syntax to `Set reg = GetObject("WinMgmts:root\default:StdRegProv")` to get it to work (@ Windows 7)...

Comment: @aschipfl Hmm... weird. I have used `GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")` on Windows 7 and other versions (older and newer) for years, if not decades.

Comment: I am sorry, stupid me, both variants work, I just had another error in the code and drew a wrong conclusion...